# COLLATE sql command is not supported in ignite SQL

Tags: sql, ignite

Following query doesn't work in ignite SQL.

```
SELECT  *  FROM <TableName>
ORDER BY   TITLE  COLLATE NOCASE ASC ;
```

Is there any way to do sorting with case insensitive??

Sample Data:

```
--------------
|  birds    |
-------------
| Hen       |
| HEN       |
| Parrot    |
| parrot    |
| peacock   |
| Sparrow   |
| hen       |
| Crow      |
| crow      |
--------------
```

Post query output should be:

```
--------------
| birds     |
-------------
| Crow      |
| crow      |
| HEN       |
| Hen       |
| hen       |
| Parrot    |
| parrot    |
| peacock   |
| Sparrow   |
-------------
```

Comment: Try:  `order b lower(title)`.

Comment: Even if you make it work, it would not use index, which would often make it useless.

Answer (score 1):

Use a LOWER/UPPER function.

```
ORDER BY UPPER(TITLE) ASC
```